# Passing object between forms c#

Tags: c#, forms, object

I have a problem with using object in functions. In Form2 im passing object to Form3:

```
DaneDelegacja Dane = new DaneDelegacja();
Dane.MiejsceDocelowe = textBox1.Text;
Dane.GodzinyWDelegacji = differenceInHours;

// Create a new instance of the Form3 class
Form3 nocleg = new Form3(Dane);
```

Form3

```
public Form3(DaneDelegacja Dane)
{
     InitializeComponent();                             
}
```

and on the function button1_click in Form3 i cant use that object "Dane" because

> "Error    1   The name 'Dane' does not exist in the current context"

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Dane.NoclegRyczalt = textBox1.Text;
        Dane.NoclegRachunek = textBox2.Text;

        // Create a new instance of the Form4 class
        Form4 posilki = new Form4();

        // Show the settings form
        posilki.Show();
        this.Hide();
}
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: create a global variable for Dane in Form3 and set it in Form3 constructor.

Comment: maybe you should copy the object-reference to some backing-field in your `Form3` class ;) (create a `private DaneDelegacja _dane` field in your class and then use `_dane = Dane` in your constructor ... you can then use `_dane` where you was expecting `Dane`)

Comment: btw just as a hint: please rename your controls (whenever I read `textBox1` I cringe) and don't mix upper/lowercase that much - the argument `Dane` should be lower case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to store it inside `Form3` . Create a field/ property and assign the value from `Dane` in the constructor:

```
public class Form3 : Form
{
  ...
  private readonly DaneDelegacja Dane;

   public Form3( DaneDelegacja Dane )
   {
      this.Dane = Dane;

      InitializeComponents();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing in an instance of the DaneDelegacija class, but you don't save that reference to Dane to Form3.

Inside Form3 you need to create a property:
    DaneDelegacija dane;

Inside Form3(DaneDelegacija Dane) you should set that property like:

```
dane = Dane; //from your constructor
```

And then call:

```
dane.NoclegRyczalt .. etc
```